# how to get fastapi docs work with docker container deployed in aks?

Tags: python, docker, azure-aks, fastapi

test endpoint which is working : baseurl/ds-clm-metadata-aks/test

OpenAPI valid json : baseurl/ds-clm-metadata-aks/openapi.json

Local container run is working : localhost:4557/docs, localhost:4557/docs

ideally docs should be rendered at : baseurl/ds-clm-metadata-aks/docs

But gives the following error :
[image]

Redoc url : baseurl/ds-clm-metadata-aks/redoc , gives error:
[image]

```
"""This package contains functions for metadata attribute extraction"""
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/test")
async def index(request: Request):
    return {"Api is running"}
```

```
  
import uvicorn

from dsclm.metadata import endpoints


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("dsclm.metadata:app", host='0.0.0.0', port=4558,
                reload=True, debug=True, workers=3)
```

Comment: Can you please show the lines where you instanciate your app ? Like `app = FastAPI(provide=your, **options)`

Comment: added code, please check

Comment: Do you deploy the application in the local machine directly or with the docker container? If you use the docker container, can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense will check this and approve answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can see what's going on. You forgot to set the "root_path" parameter, either to Uvicorn or in FastAPI app constructor. And this raises what you can see.

Please adjust the "root_path" either in Uvicorn part (recommended) or in FastAPI part (drawback). Read this for full explanations : https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy

Comment: BTW, this has no connection with Docker or Kubernetes. This is just because you installed a proxy that transfers incoming requests to  http://yoursite/ds-clm-metadata-aks to your uvicorn app root.